# filter result with $match and regular expressions inside $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregates

I have this Aggregation pipeline.
I am able to get the data I need with additional function like sorting and pagination.
I used $lookup to add documents I need from other collections.

```
[ { '$match': { status: [Object] } },
  { '$lookup': { from: 'users', as: 'owner', let: { owner: "$owner" }, pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$owner", "$_id"] } } },
        { $unwind: { path:"$subscriptions", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false} },
        { $match: { "subscriptions.active": true } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "plans",
            localField: "subscriptions.plan_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "subscriptions.plans"
          }
        },
  ] }},     
  { '$unwind': { path: '$owner', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },      
  { '$sort': { location: 1 } },
  { '$skip': 0 },
  { '$limit': 20 }
]
```

But now, I need to filter these results with search function.
I want to use regex with case insensitive to match results.
How can I use regex with $match?
How can I use $gte and $lte with $match for date range?

I tried using $regexMatch like,

```
{$match: {$regexMatch: {new RegExp(variableName, 'i')}}
```

but failed.

Also on $lookup for plans, how can I use $match there to filter results that have only plans from regex?

Comment: Post some sample data

Comment: Kindly provide what sample data you need. Thank you.

Comment: Your both collections samples and desired output